# retornar para uma Nav tab especifica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um controller, que depois que salva, ele precisa ser derecionado para uma tab especifica, então eu uso como reterno os seguintes parametros.

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Editar/" + resultado.Id, "ClienteEmpresa") + "#nav-profile");
```

Com isso eu consigo, pegar na url, exatamente, a o que eu quero, porém não sei como faço para que a Nav-Tab, #nav-profile,  seja a que abra, pois ainda estás a abrir, a primeira Tab.

Minha Url fica dessa forma ao abrir

```
http://localhost:51029/ClienteEmpresa/Editar/14#nav-profile
```

Porém a tab que vem aberta é a `#nav-home-tab`

Esse aqui é meu HTML.

```
<div class="default-tab col-lg-12">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Empresa</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Contador</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-bloqueios-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-bloqueios" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-bloqueios" aria-selected="false">Bloqueios</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-financeiro-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-financeiro" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-financeiro" aria-selected="false">Controle de Vencimentos</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-cobranca-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-cobranca" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-cobranca" aria-selected="false">Controle De Cobranças</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content pl-3 pt-2" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">


        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="nav-bloqueios" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-bloqueios-tab">
            @Html.Action("_tblBloqueios", new { Id = Model.Id })
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="nav-financeiro" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-financeiro-tab">
            @Html.Action("_tableVencimentos", new { Id = Model.Id })
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="nav-cobranca" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-cobranca-tab">
            @Html.Action("_tableControleDeCobranca", new { Id = Model.Id })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como eu posso fazer isso? não manjo muito de Js e nem Jquery. então toda e qualquer dica será bem vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso será necessário verificar a presença de um # na url.

```
function afterLoad(){
    var url = location.href;
    var splittedUrl = url.split("#");
    if (splittedUrl.length >= 2) {
        var goToTabAriaControls = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length-1];
        $('a[aria-controls="' + goToTabAriaControls + '"]').click();
    } else {
        //implemente aqui o código caso não seja encontrada a presença de um #
    }
}
```

Você pode executar o código acima sempre que houver o carrega da página, por exemplo, no final da `View` você poderia colocar esse código e executá-lo `afterLoad()` logo em seguida, ou colocar esse código num arquivo javascript previamente inserido e apenas executar o método, sendo que a execução ainda estaria na `View`.

Nessa resposta é verificada a presença do `#` na url e é utilizada última parte encontrada para realizar a ação do click.

`goToTabAriaControls` sempre será a string que se encontra após o último `#` encontrado.

Comment: É necessário prestar atenção que NÃO existe espaçamento entre o `a` e o `[`

Comment: subarashi!, cara, de todos que eu fucei na net, (e olha que eu to com mais de 5 hora de pesquisa, o seu script/explicação, foi a unica que funcionou. muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! Fico feliz em ter ajudado

Comment: Não querendo abusar, mas aproveitando o gancho, teria como além de eu direcionar para a tab, ainda abrir uma modal? pq a verdade é que o objetivo principal é essa, é uma regra. (depois que eu clicar em salvar para adicionar o cliente, obrigatoriamente, eu tenho que mandar o usuário para a aba #nav-profile, nessa aba eu tenho um botão que abre um modal para adicionar um contador, mas a verdade, é que era para abrir na aba, e ja abrir a modal.

Comment: Após executar o `.click()` verifique qual o valor de `goToTabAriaControls` se for o `nav-profile` abra a modal

Comment: `if (goToTabAriaControls == 'nav-profile') {
                    $("#addContador").load("_addContador?id=" + id, function () {
                        $("#addContador").modal();
                    });

                }` assim?

Comment: Creio que seria isso mesmo

Comment: Não deu muito certo, mas vou continuar pesquisando aqui hehe, já é meio caminho andado!!